# array_contains query on Objects

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I had a *field in every document of a collection* called `array_field`, which consists of *elements of type `object`*, could I query for a *specific field in the objects*?

```
- collection

  - document1
    - array_field
      0: { type: tree, age: 143 }
      1: { type: sunflower, age: 1 }
      2: { type: fungus, age: 3 }

  - document2
    - array_field
      0: { type: plane, age: 38 }
      1: { type: plant, age: 2 }
      2: { type: fungus, age: 1 }
```

Is there a possibility to query for every document that has an object *in its **`array_field`** with type `fungus`*?

If that is not possible, is there a way to query for documents by specifying an *exact `object`*?
I do not know how I would go about writing the query: `.where('array_field', 'array_contains', /*how do I define this object*/)`. Would it just be a JSON object like this: `{type: fungus, age: 2}`?

The query I am aiming to achieve is the following:

```
where('array_field', 'array_contains', 'type:fungus')
```

Which would return `document1` and `document2`, but I could not find any hints on syntax for a case like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible with the current structure of your data.  array_contains only works when matching the *entire* contents of an array element, not just specific object fields.

Instead, you could restructure you data to use an object with unique types, and a boolean value, so that you could query for something like `types.fungus == true`:

```
document
    types {
        fungus: true
        plant: true
    }
```

It is common to duplicate data in nosql database to suit the specific queries you need to perform.